# Scala: PartialFunction weird behavior

Tags: scala

It's weird but my code prints `u`. Any ideas why does it do such stuff?

```
object PF extends App {
  val f1: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case x: Int if x % 2 == 0 => "2"
  }

  val f2: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case x: Int if x % 3 == 0 => "3"
  }

  val f3: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case x: Int if x % 5 == 0 => "5"
  }

  val result = f1.orElse(f2.orElse(f3.orElse("<undef>")))
  println(result.apply(1))    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code interprets the string "" as `PartialFunction`:

```
val result: PartialFunction[Int, String] = "<undef>"
result.apply(1) // second character of "<undef>" --> u
```

This happens through an implicit conversion from `String` to [`WrappedString`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) which is a subtype of `Seq[Char]`. Further, `Seq[T]` is a subtype of `PartialFunction[Int, T]` (given an index, get an element of the `Seq` if it exists).

The last line reaches this case, since 1 is not divisible by any of 2,3,5 (so it falls through `f1`, `f2` and `f3`).

What you would want instead is `applyOrElse`:

```
val fun = f1 orElse f2 orElse f3
fun.applyOrElse(1, "<undef>") // --> "<undef>"
```

Alternatively, you can specify a fallback partial function:

```
val result = f1 orElse f2 orElse f3 orElse {
  case _ => "<undef>"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. But why compiler allows to substitute types (PartialFunction -> String)? My guess is there is some implicit conversion that substitute a PF with a String. But I can't find it.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Hope this is clear :)